# Absolute positioned inner content goes beyond the outer boundary on width of 100%

Tags: html, css, css-position, carousel, absolute

When I place a full (100%) `width` content i.e. `carousel-indicators` (in the below code) inside another `div` i.e. `wpr` and remove the `padding` (set to 0), why does still the inner content goes beyond the outer `div`. I could observe if I remove the `absolute` `position` of inner `div` i.e. `carousel-indicators` , it works as expected. Could anyone please explain me why does absolute positioning screw up?

```css
.wpr {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wpr-item {
  width: 300px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wpr-item .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 97%;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="wpr-item">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning removes the element from the document flow.

Comment: You need to declare `position: relative` to the parent element, in this case `.wpr`, so that the element positioned `absolute` has a `relative` reference to the given parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `position: relative` to the parent element, in this case `.wpr`, so that the element positioned `absolute` has a `relative` reference to the given parent element.

```css
.wpr {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wpr-item {
  width: 300px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wpr-item .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 97%;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="wpr-item">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default `ol/ul` tag take some `margin & padding`. You can remove that to resolve your issue. & add `position: relative;` to `.wpr` div. check updated snippet below

```css
.wpr {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wpr-item {
  width: 300px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wpr-item .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 97%;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="wpr-item">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```